# Installation of OzCode on VS 2012 Update 2 Windows 8 64bit

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging, debuggervisualizer, ozcode

I have downloaded the latest version of OzCode (OzCode_0.9.3426.6578_6988) and while I tried to install it. The visual studio integration page of OzCode setup lists the VS versions but the the checkbox next to the VS version is not clickable( can't check the checkbox, disabled); the next button is disabled also; If I click on back button now and then next button is enabled( but VS Version checkbox is still un checkable) and then if I install it; OzCode doesn't appear in VS 2012 Menu. (Other than that there is no installation error)

What is happening ? I am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Visual Studio Express? That might explain it, as Visual Studio Express does not support extensions.